# How does kube apiserver communicates with kubelet and kube-proxy?

Tags: kubernetes, iot, kubelet, kube-proxy, kubernetes-apiserver

I'm interested if I can run k8s with publicly available control plane and worker nodes in network behind firewall (which is edge/iot deployment use-case). The main concern as I believe is communication between apiserver and kubelet/ kube-proxy. Can it be configured as only node -> master communication? How can I achieve this?

I could not find precisize info besides this short note in kubelet [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/):
`HTTP endpoint: HTTP endpoint passed as a parameter on the command line. This endpoint is checked every 20 seconds (also configurable with a flag).`

For kube-proxy I could not find any info.

I'm also new to golang so analyzing the k8s source code is for now beyond my skill. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can it be configured as only node -> master communication? How can I achieve this?

I would guess only trying it will prove for sure that the apiserver doesn't need to contact `kubelet`. However, related to that: be aware that in such a setup, `kubectl exec` and `kubectl logs` will no longer function because those commands connect directly to port 10254 on the kubelet binary instead of sending all that traffic through the API server

As for kube-proxy, [it appears](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.17.0/cluster/addons/kube-proxy/kube-proxy-ds.yaml#L46-L47) it uses the in-cluster `$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` which will be the `.1` IP of the `Service` CIDR and will use the software defined network to reach the apiserver. Although there are [other configurations](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.17.0/cluster/gce/manifests/kube-proxy.manifest#L60-L61) which volume mount a `kubeconfig` from the host, so I guess the ultimate answer will depend on how you installed your cluster.

Comment: Thak you! I did some tets and I was able to add node. The kube-proxy and calico pods were scheduled. The kubelete posts status of node to apiserver. However, the container runtime crashes because of some OS misconfiguration so I wasn't able to run any workloads on node added. Full answer will be soon :)